# How to Get web page columns innerText using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing an EpubReader Application and I need to get the inner text of layout column in My Application JavaScript Side.

Because My Application opens different epubs The **HTML tags** formatting **is not the same**.

My single page Epub in 5 inch Android device screen :
[image: Epub columns]

They are There columns here and I want to get their text to **store** them in an array
 with the length that is **as much as columns count**
 and do some some operation on them.

```js
   var bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
 /* other codes*/
    bodyElement.style.columnFill = 'auto';
    bodyElement.style.height = pageHeight + 'px';
    bodyElement.style.webkitColumnGap = (paddingLeft + paddingRight) + 'px';
    bodyElement.style.webkitColumnWidth = pageWidth + 'px';
    bodyElement.style.width = newBodyWidth + 'px';
```

Is There any way to get columns text  in javaScript??
**Thanks in advance :)**

Comment: Without the html code it is rather impossible to give an answer. Try to include the html view in your snippet

Comment: As I said in my question ,my application opens different epub files with different HTML file tag formatting . for example one epub html file have just  one p tag with 14 line text and other epub html file have 13 separate p tags and one div tag with a p tag consist of 1 text line